# drop_duplicates() not working because it does not find any duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I started to work with Pandas last week, so I might miss something, but here's my issue. When scraping product reviews on an online shop, I obtained the IDs of the users who wrote the reviews. Because I wanted to have additional data, I expanded a dataframe to collect all other reviews for other products written by these users. So, logically, when I'm expanding the dataframe, I should find twice the same user_ID, review_text and product_ID (the product for which the user wrote the review). Hence, my dataframe looks like this basically for a given user:

| index | product_id | product_num_review | product_review_score | user_id | user_review_text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1186030 | 6 | 0 | 76561197971290677 | Garbage product! |
| 470 | 1239050 | NaN | NaN | 76561197971290677 | I like it |
| 471 | 1311250 | NaN | NaN | 76561197971290677 | Meh |
| 472 | 1186030 | NaN | NaN | 76561197971290677 | Garbage product! |
| 473 | 1197370 | NaN | NaN | 76561197971290677 | Good! |

So here, I have two duplicates, the row 5 and the row 472. There is NaN in row 472 because when expanding the reviews and scraping this review, I was not able to scrape other information (like the number of reviews of this product for instance.)

As it might be trailing whitespace or perhaps the reviews could have been modified between the two instances (very unlikely but still), I excluded to check duplicates according to the text of the reviews, but rather decided to delete rows that had the same pair of product_id/user_id.

```
df =df.drop_duplicates(subset=["product_id", "user_id"], keep="first")
```

The issue here is that pandas does not detect any duplicates! I verified it by doing:

```
df.duplicated(subset=["product_id", "user_id"])
```

And all that is returned are False, meaning that no duplicates have been found.

**What I have tried:**
I checked to see if the problem was related to the column type, and after doing

```
print(df.dtypes)
```

It tells me that both product_id and user_id are object types. Converting them to int or str did not change the result.

So here I am, not knowing what is the problem here. For there is duplicates, that is for sure, but why pandas is not detecting it? I'm sure that is a rookie mistake, but I'm a bit lost here. Thank for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that there aren't any additional white-spaces?

Comment: It just worked, of course after I posted the question aha! What I did is to convert columns in int, and it worked. I thought I did it, but apparently not.

Comment: So it works? cool

Comment: Look at the column names as well. There is "product_ID" in your dataframe, but you try to find duplicates in column "product_id".

Comment: Oh yes, sorry about that. It was a type, it's indeed product_id in my dataframe. I have edited my post, thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, so I solve the issue, even if I'm not sure I could explain it.
I wrote in my question that I tried to convert the columns in int, but apparently I wrote it in the wrong way the first time. So what I did is the following:

```
df2["product_id"] = pd.to_numeric(df2["product_id"])
df2["user_id"] = pd.to_numeric(df2["user_id"])
```

And it worked!